# Draw Vertical Label using draw2d in eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, draw2d

I am doing an Eclipse plugin using gef. Does anybody knows how to draw 
a vertical label?

Kind Regards,
Kyriakos Georgiou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/164346/726021/#msg_726021) thread, at the end of the thread.

Answer (score 1):

Using ImageUtilities as in the linked post worked well. Here is how to use it in a Label.

```
@Override
protected void paintFigure(Graphics graphics) {
    if (vertical) {
        Image image = ImageUtilities.createRotatedImageOfString(getSubStringText(), getFont(), getForegroundColor(), getBackgroundColor());
        graphics.drawImage(image, new Point(getTextLocation()).translate(getLocation()));
    image.dispose();
    } else {
        super.paintFigure(graphics);
    }
}
```

Comment: would it be good practice to cache the image and only dispose it when the label is disposed? What method is the best to dispose the image? Label#removeNotify?